# Can a software cause a huge ping response

Tags: ping, cmd.exe

I need someone to explain something to me since I'm really not good with networking.
How can it be that when I open minecraft and I mouse over the ping I see 1300+ms and I lag extremely.

But when I ping the server itself in the CMD I get all fast responses like 24ms.

- I don't have a "bad" connection "20mb / 10mb" and nothing is used on the connection.
- I did a full reset on the rooter and modem
- I tried other games where I don't lag at all and my ping is around 30
- One of my friend lives across the street with a similar connection and gets a ping of 20 on the server.

Can it be the program itself causing the issue ?

Comment: Yes. Extremely busy CPU can cause that, check for it. Also verify if network utilization is below 10% so the connection is really not congested.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Asked my friend to try it. The problem is on the network... he has the same ping. We are on a lan switch. But it never caused a problem before. I'll try plugging myself into the router directly instead of the switch.

Comment: @FreeConsulting The switch was not the problem. THe CPU is in the low % so is the network... Also I can reproduce this issue everywhere on my network (all computers and laptops). Can the server have a problem with our connection ?

Comment: Don't hurry, verify what problem is on network first (and not in the Minecraft internal ping, as Oliver said). Run `ping -t 8.8.8.8` and then check out if starting Minecraft have any effect on the round trip time. That will be an answer for your Q.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Nice I didn't know that trick. I tried it. Ping was aroun 40 to 50 going on 55 sometimes when minecraft was opened but no major spikes. :(

Comment: This means the problem is specific to Minecraft exchanges. I know nothing about Minecraft, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The ping that is sent from the `ping` tool on the command line is an [ICMP PING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol). This uses a simple protocol that is designed for this.

Minecraft will probably implement its own type of a "ping". It will probably send a packet to the game server which only a Minecraft server will understand. This can have much higher response times.

When you send a simple ICMP PING, then that is handled by the operating system without any application ever knowing about it.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that ! Now, I've added troubleshooting steps above. What would you try next to pinpoint the issue ? I'm running low on ideas..

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: Well, you could try connecting to the server from a different computer in your network. Or try booting into a live Linux system and install Minecraft there to see if some software or your own OS has an impact on this issue. You need to determine which elements in your setup impact your connection to the server. There are a lot of options. Once you have a better idea, you should post a separate question about that specific issue.

Comment: Thanks I eliminated various options as of now. Everybody on my networks as that issue. If I did a trace route from me to the server, and then one from my friend that doesn't have the problem to the server and put them both in another question, is this enough details to see where the lag is ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: That depends on if there is a difference ;) But it would be a good start. You could also join us in [chat] to see if we can narrow down the issue before you take it to a new question. BTW, when troubleshooting an issue like this, you might want to look at `pathping` instead of `traceroute`

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a specific chatroom I should use for that ? Or is there a way to transform these comment into a chat.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access) is our main chatroom. You can post a reference to the this question there if needed