# What is most likely to cause this packet loss?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, packet

This question: [Can a software cause a huge ping response](https://superuser.com/questions/681323/can-a-software-cause-a-huge-ping-response) is what made me realize that I have a network problem.

As you can see here:

```
C:\Users\*****>pathping google.com

Tracing route to google.com [74.125.226.142]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
0  *****[192.168.0.100]
1  10.245.129.129
2  videotron-tek.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.109]
3  videotron-tek.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.109]
4  2150.ae1.bdr04.tor.man.teksavvy.com.packetflow.ca [69.196.136.164]
5  72.14.212.134
6  209.85.255.232
7  209.85.250.7
8  yyz08s14-in-f14.1e100.net [74.125.226.142]

Computing statistics for 200 seconds...
        Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
0                                           Sektor [192.168.0.100]
                           10/ 100 = 10%   |
1  ---     100/ 100 =100%    90/ 100 = 90%  10.245.129.129
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
2   27ms    13/ 100 = 13%     3/ 100 =  3%  videotron-tek.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.109]
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
3   26ms    12/ 100 = 12%     2/ 100 =  2%  videotron-tek.teksavvy.com [206.248.155.109]
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
4   24ms    19/ 100 = 19%     9/ 100 =  9%  2150.ae1.bdr04.tor.man.teksavvy.com.packetflow.ca [69.196.136.164]
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
5   26ms    19/ 100 = 19%     9/ 100 =  9%  72.14.212.134
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
6   25ms    10/ 100 = 10%     0/ 100 =  0%  209.85.255.232
                            5/ 100 =  5%   |
7  ---     100/ 100 =100%    85/ 100 = 85%  209.85.250.7
                            0/ 100 =  0%   |
8   22ms    15/ 100 = 15%     0/ 100 =  0%  yyz08s14-in-f14.1e100.net [74.125.226.142]

Trace complete.
```

I have a whole lot of packet loss only when doing a `pathping` on google.com.
What is most likely to cause these packet losses?

- My cables
- My LAN Switch
- My modem
- My router
- My ISP
- Ethernet collisions

1. My cables are pretty old but still, can cables really make you lose that many packets? (average 13%)

2. My switch could be the cause, but I plugged myself into the router directly to test and I still got the same results.

3. My modem: I guess I could change it, but since I switched to 20MB, I got a new one so it shouldn't be a problem either.

4. My router is a D-Link Dir-655 Gigabyte, so it is not so old. Do routers accumulate data that stays there even after a full reset?  Because that could explain, that with the time and the usage I made, I should have changed it by now.

5. My ISP: I don't want to get there. You all know I won't get what I'm looking for unless I change every single part on my side and even then I would have to wait for a very long time to maybe get a chance to see a solution.

6. Ethernet collisions: I have 12 devices on wifi/cable at home. Maybe my router isn't able to support that many devices syncing and it causes problems with it.

Is there something that comes out of all this? Because I don't want to be buying a $200 router or a new switch or even open a painful case with my ISP support before knowing if something obvious is coming out of all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was my Ethernet Card for some reason.
Ruled out all of the options above and then bought a "usb wi-fi" key to bypass my ethernet card to see if it was causing the losses.

Turns out it was.